# How to use dot2texi in Lyx

Tags: lyx, graphs

I am trying to use dot2texi package in Lyx to generate graphs, and I include the following in the preamble of the document:

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% recommended as of Pgfplots 1.3:
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
```

And I insert a block of Tex code inside my Lyx document:

```
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,options=-tmath]
digraph G 
{
    node [shape="circle"]; 
    a_1 -> a_2 -> a_3 -> a_4 -> a_1;
}
\end{dot2tex}}
```

as taken from the example here: http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/documentation/#the-dot2texi-latex-package

However, when I view the document in PDF format, it doesn't show anything nor throw any error - nothing. Btw, I am using the latest Lyx 2.0.0. Any suggestion what could have gone wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this problem and managed to fix it in the following way:
The preamble:

```
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
```

Not sure if the load order matters, but you need to include both the `tikz` the `pgf` packages or specify that you explicitly want to use `tikz` in your graphs.

The latter is done like this:

```
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,tikz,options=-tmath]
```

I'm not sure if it possible to specify this somewhere global for your whole document.

Also don't forget to enable `-shell-escape` in the call to pdflatex, this can be done in `Preferences > File Handlers > Converters` by changing the `LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)` to `pdflatex -shell-escape $$i`.